# Confluent hypergeometric integrand over finite domain

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, special-functions

[Tricomi's (confluent hypergeometric) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations) is $$U(a,b,z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^\infty  e^{-zt}t^{a-1}(1+t)^{b-a-1}dt$$ for $\Re(a)>0$.

Is there any analytical expression/special function for the integral over a *finite* domain $$\int_x^y  e^{-zt}t^{a-1}(1+t)^{b-a-1}dt,$$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ are constants?

Comment: The confluent hypergeometric function is already highly specialized and is not even really a "closed form" in the eyes of many. Why do you expect the finite integral to have a nice result?

Comment: @K.defaoite ''closed-form'' is perhaps the wrong word, I'm sorry. Tricomi's function is ''not nice'', granted, but it's a well-studied special function which can be very quickly evaluated by Maple, Matlab, Python ... I wonder whether such a special function also exists for the same integrand over a finite domain. Basically, does this finite domain integral have a special name, has it popped up somewhere else, does it have special properties that allow for quick numerical evaluations?

Comment: If you integrate $t^{a - 1} (1 + t)^{b - a - 1} (-z t)^k$ from $0$ to $x$, you get a ${_2 F_1}$ function. Summing over $k$ gives an antiderivative in terms of the Humbert series $\Phi_1$:
$$\int_0^x t^{a - 1} (1 + t)^{b - a - 1} e^{-z t} dt =
\frac {x^a} a \Phi_1(a, a - b + 1, a + 1; -x, -z x).$$

Comment: @Maxim That occurs to be the hint I was looking for! Could you please provide a reference for the Humbert series because [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series) expresses it as an integral from 0 to 1 (and not some $x$).

Comment: How do you compute a definite integral if you know an antiderivative? :) The sum of hypergeometric functions is equal to the double series for $\Phi_1$ when $|x| < 1$. Analytic continuations will coincide by the identity theorem.

Comment: @Maxim haha, the antiderivative point is clear now, sorry! That was silly of me. If you could add answer with the key equations, then I can accept and upvote it! :)

Comment: Feel free to add an answer. If you start with the integral representation of $\Phi_1$ which you were referring to, it suffices to just make the substitution $t = x u$ in the integral on the lhs in my first comment, use the fact that $(x u)^{a - 1} = x^{a - 1} u^{a - 1}$ for $u > 0$ and compare with the integral representation of the rhs.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you so much for your help and effort. It's greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Maxim Perhaps one final question if I may: given that the Gamma functions cancel and don't appear in the final equation, is it possible that the condition $\Re(a)>0$ is unncessary and the antiderivative holds for all values of $a,b,z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Consider a simpler example $F = \int_0^x t^a dt$. $F$ is defined only for $\operatorname {Re} a > -1$ and, unless $a \in \mathbb N^0$, $F(x)$ has a branch cut. If the segment $[z_1, z_2]$ doesn't cross the branch cut of $F(x)$, we can use $F$ to evaluate $\int_{z_1}^{z_2}$. The equality obtained for this $[z_1, z_2]$ can now be extended to all $a$ because both sides extend to entire functions of $a$, which have to coincide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was given by **@Maxim** in the comments. The special function is called **Humbert series**. With the integral representation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series), a substitution $t=ux$ immediately implies

$$\int_0^x (1+t)^{b-a-1}t^{a-1}e^{-zt} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{x^a}{a} \Phi_1(a,a-b+1,a+1;-x,-zx)$$

because $\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(a+1)}=\frac{1}{a}$.